# Installing Python package from version control where setup.py is not in the project root

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, pyobjc

I'm trying to include the [pyobjc](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc) package in my pip requirements file, but I need a committed version that doesn't have a release yet in order to pull in a much needed bug fix. The pyobjc package is a pseudo-package to install all the other framework dependencies.

I can specify the HG path in the pip requirements just fine. The problem I'm facing is that the repository doesn't have a setup.py in the root directory. Instead it has a subdirectory labeled pyobjc (with all the framework subdirectories alongside) that contains setup.py. In the root directory of the repo, there's a file labeled install.py that pyobjc's [readme](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/src/e745884d66960b68434ce6a4a3c3b56835c22a8d/ReadMe.rst) recommends using when installing from source.

Does anyone have any idea how to call install.py from pip instead of setup.py or point to the subdirectory location?

Answer (score 0):

In the [pyobjc/pyobjc subdirectory](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/src/39c254b20bf2d63ef2891cb57bba027dfe7e06e8/pyobjc/?at=default) I see `setup.py`, not `install.py.

`pip` can be [advised](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support) to look into a subdirectory of a VCS repository for `setup.py`:

```
pip install -e 'hg+https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc@39c254b20bf2d63ef2891cb57bba027dfe7e06e8#egg=pyobjc&subdirectory=pyobjc'
```